# Total angular momentum in multielectron atoms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atoms, spectroscopy, spherical-harmonics

I have some confusion about orbitals in multielectron atoms.

Let's say we consider an atom (Lithium, for example, $1s^2\, 2p^1$) and that the state of the last electron is [n=2, l=1, ml=0, s=1/2, ms=1/2]. Its wave equation should then be $$\psi(r,\theta,\phi)=R_{nl}(r)Y_{lm_l}(\theta,\phi)\chi_s(m_s)$$

Now we want to apply "LS coupling". Since the Hamiltonian for the perturbation commutes with $J^2$ and $J_z$ we express the wave function in terms of the eigenstates of these operators. So, we search for the [Clebsch-Gordan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients) coefficients and we have that $j$ can be either $1/2$ or $3/2$, and $j_z$ can vary in integer steps between $-j$ and $j$. So, if I understood well, we have 6 Clebsch-Gordan coefficients to care about, let's call them $K_{[l=1,m_l=0,s=1/2,m_s=1/2]}(j,j_z)$ and our wave equation should become:
$$\psi(r,\theta,\phi)=\sum_{j=1/2,3/2}\sum_{m_j=-j}^j K_{[l=1,m_l=0,s=1/2,m_s=1/2]}(j,j_z)R_{nl}(r)Y_{jm_j}(\theta,\phi)$$

Now I'd like some clarification:

1. The spherical harmonics with the same parameters should be the same function. Are the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients and the spherical harmonics tuned such that $\sum_{j=1/2,3/2}\sum_{m_j=-j}^j K_{[l=1,m_l=0,s=1/2,m_s=1/2]}(j,j_z)Y_{jm_j}=Y_{lm_l}\chi_s(m_s)$? This seems reasonable, but what happens to the spin? How is it inglobed inside the $Y_{jm_j}$?
2. When you have more then one electron in the outer shell, from what I understood, you treat the "collection of electrons" as a *system* with a certain $s$, $l$, $j$ and $m_j$. Am I right?